Why are the added Safe Operations to the Safe Service do not appear in the Safe UI?
I am adding a signedSafeOperation into the Safe Service by using await apiKit.addSafeOperation(signedSafeOperation)
It is an operation in a Safe with a threshold > 1, and it has one signature.
When I run the addSafeOperation(signedSafeOperation) I see that the operation is added to the Safe Service and even when I do
await apiKit.getSafeOperationsByAddress({
   safeAddress: SAFE_ADDRESS
})

I do get a result like the following
pendingUserOperations {
  count: 5,
  next: null,
  previous: null,
  results: [
    {
    ....
    }
]}...


Question is

Aren't these operations supposed to be shown in the Safe UI?
As in the queue?
At the end, these are operations that have 1 signature and are pending to be confirmed by the other signers. I would expect to see them here, as if it was a regular transaction that started from the Safe UI.


Thanks!

Thanks for your great question.
Currently, the Safe Wallet UI does not support 4337 user operations.
User operations are not displayed, as they differ from "normal" Safe transactions and go to a different mempool (depending on your 4337 provider, they only go to the provider and not to a mempool). When the user operation get's executed, they will show up as module transactions, because internally Safe Smart Accounts use a module to execute 4337 transactions.
If this answers your question, please mark it as answered.
